# How can I stop Visual Studio from automatically inserting the Namespace when I reference a class?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Whenever I'm defining a variable or assigning a value to one, if the value or definition for the variable references a class or property that exists in a different namespace, Visual Studio has developed this annoying habit of including the Namespace name in there even though I've added the Namespace to my usings.

Consider the following:

```
using MyDemoApp.DataModel;

protected void btnSubmit_Click(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ...
}
```

As soon as I've finished off the line that declares `Context`, Visual Studio will change the line to read as

```
ApplicationDbContext Context = new DataModel.ApplicationDbContext();
```

The insult here is that it then gives me a refactor option to simplify the name as if I'm the idiot who added the redundant code.

How can I change this behavior so that Visual Studio just leaves the declaration as I wrote it in the first place?

Comment: It's a bug in Visual Studio 2015. I use 2017 now but I'll confess I don't know if it's fixed or not.

Comment: @HansPassant I did that. They closed the issue as a duplicate of another and said "its fixed in VS 2017" as if that's even remotely helpful to me while I'm using VS 2015... What a joke.