# Why does VS-Intellisense sometimes "use" the namespace and prepend it to a type in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, intellisense

Why does VS-intellisense sometimes write `using` at the top of the page and sometimes adds it inline like `new namespace.class` in C#?

For example

```
using Namespace;
Obj obj = new Obj();
```

and

```
obj = new Namespace.Obj();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes two namespaces have the same class. So to avoid ambiguity the namespace is added to the class .

Example: 
Imagine that you have  Namespace1 and  Namespace2 and both of them has the class `Employee`

```
using Namespace1;
using Namespace2;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    private Employee emp1; // does it come from Namespace1 or Namespace2 ? 
  }
}
```

So two solutions can be done in this case

one is to have the name space explecitly defined

```
using Namespace1;
using Namespace2;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    private Namespace1.Employee emp1; 
  }
}
```

and the other is that you define from the beginning that you are using the Employee from a certain namespace as follows.

```
using Namespace1;
using Namespace2;
using Employee = Namespace1.Employee; 

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    private Employee emp1; //Notice the definition above
  }
}
```

Comment: Weired because i have two projects one downloaded (first case ) and the second written by me (second case ) I think Ortund is more accurate

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 has a bug where it does this.

Whether or not you include a `using` statement at the top of your code file, the bug causes it to add the namespace in front of your definition.

[I asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238288/how-can-i-stop-visual-studio-from-automatically-inserting-the-namespace-when-i-r) a few weeks ago and, on the recommendation of another user, submitted an issue on the relevant github project.

My issue was closed almost immediately with a rather snippy comment which basically said "update to Visual Studio 2017 because we fixed it in that version".

Comment: Actually I am using VS 2013